# How to save automatically with append comment to file name?

Tags: bash, file, loops

I am extracting data from files and I'd like to apply these working (ugly) command lines to all the txt files from a given folder. Thus I would also need to append a string to the output file name to avoid overwriting during the loop... any suggestion is warmly welcome.

```
for file in ./TEST/;
    do 
        awk '/R.Time/,/LC/' 070_WT3a.txt|awk '/R.Time/,/PDA/'|grep -v -E "PDA|LC"|grep -w -v "80,00000"|grep -w -v "80,00833"|grep -w -v "80,01667"|grep -w -v "80,01067"|grep -w -v "80,02133"|sed -n '1,9601p' > ./Output/Fluo.txt;
        awk '/R.Time/,/LC/' 070_WT3a.txt|awk '/R.Time/,/PDA/'|grep -v -E "PDA|LC"|grep -w -v "80,00000"|grep -w -v "80,00833"|grep -w -v "80,01667"|grep -w -v "80,01067"|grep -w -v "80,02133"|sed -n '9603,19203p' > ./Output/RID.txt;
    done
```

Comment: Could you give some sample data and a possible output?

Comment: several `grep -w -v` commands can be avoided by using -e option.

Comment: Here are a simplified input and two output files...
[link] (https://wetransfer.com/downloads/19a43e49c6e5f7a2dbb7271fa0a8c73f20171017103451/218961)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the loop you can use the variable `${file}`. A first improvement (with additional lines that you can add after a pipe) :

```
for file in ./TEST/;
do 
   filebasename=${file##*/}
   awk '/R.Time/,/LC/' ${file}.txt |
      awk '/R.Time/,/PDA/' |
      grep -v -E "PDA|LC" |
      grep -w -v "80,00000"|
      grep -w -v "80,00833"|
      grep -w -v "80,01667"|
      grep -w -v "80,01067"|
      grep -w -v "80,02133"|
      sed -n '1,9601p' > ./Output/Fluo_${filebasename};
   awk '/R.Time/,/LC/' 070_WT3a.txt |
      awk '/R.Time/,/PDA/'|
      grep -v -E "PDA|LC"|
      grep -w -v "80,00000"|
      grep -w -v "80,00833"|
      grep -w -v "80,01667"|
      grep -w -v "80,01067"|
      grep -w -v "80,02133"|
      sed -n '9603,19203p' > ./Output/RID_${filebasename};
done
```

The next thing you can do is improving the parsing.
Without example input/output it is hard to see/test a solution, I can not tell for sure that all files needs to be split on lines 9601/9603/19203, what seems to be working for 070_WT3a.txt. 
I would like to start with skipping the `80*` lines, but these lines might have the boundaries R.Time/LC inside, so that won't help.
You might want to test on `070_WT3a.txt` with

```
awk '/R.Time/,/LC/' 070_WT3a.txt |awk '/R.Time/,/PDA/'|
   grep -v -E "PDA|LC"|grep -Ewv "80,0(0000|0833|1667|1067|2133)"
```

You can try to combine the 2 `awk`'s into one (or even get the `grep`'s inside the `awk`, but that is becoming offtopic and difficult to test without clear requirements and examples.

EDIT:
After testing with an example input I found this simplified:

```
for file in TEST/*.txt; do 
   filebasename=${file##*/}
   awk '/LC Chromatogram(Detector A-Ch1)/,/^80,/' "${file}" | 
      grep -E "^[0-7]" > Output/Fluo_${filebasename}
   awk '/LC Chromatogram(Detector B-Ch1)/,/^80,/' "${file}" |
      grep -E "^[0-7]" > Output/RID_${filebasename}
done
```

Inside the loop I use ${file}, that will have different filenames each loop.
The filenaam is also used for the name of the outputfiles. The filename will start with `TEST/`, that can be stripped with `${file##*/}` (there are a lot different ways like using `cut -d"/"` and `sed 's/..`, this one is fast).

Comment: Here are a simplified input and two output files...
[link] (https://wetransfer.com/downloads/19a43e49c6e5f7a2dbb7271fa0a8c73f20171017103451/218961)

Comment: awk '/R.Time/,/LC/' 070_WT3a.txt |awk '/R.Time/,/PDA/'|grep -v -E "PDA|LC"|grep -Ewv "80,0(0000|0833|1667|1067|2133)"

Comment: Try something like `awk '/LC Chromatogram(Detector A-Ch1)/,/^80,/' 070_WT3a.txt  | grep -E "^[0-7]"` and `awk '/LC Chromatogram(Detector B-Ch1)/,/^80,/' 070_WT3a.txt | grep -E "^[0-7]"`, but these are besides the original question.

Comment: The latest comment works fine, but the loop just give errors like this:
bash: ./Output/Fluo_./Test/.txt: No such file or directory
awk: fatal: cannot open file `./Test/.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
bash: ./Output/RID_./Test/.txt: No such file or directory
awk: fatal: cannot open file `./Test/.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
???

Comment: after several additional tries, the loop works!!! 
Walter A, you made my day, many thanks